# Acumatica API Endpoint for Quick Checks

Tags: acumatica

I want to be able to put and get data from Quick Checks however from Version 17.200.001, there is no endpoint for it. How do I work around this issue in Acumatica?

I tried using Bill and Check endpoint but from the forms UI, both doesn't have Quick Checks as a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no entity in the endpoint for it you will need to add one in order to be able to access the data for that screen.

I would recommend that you take a look at the following help article in order to extend the default endpoint and add a new entity to it.

Article to Extend an existing endpoint :

2018R2 : https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c450492e-06fe-4563-95c3-efa76975415b

2019R1 : https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c450492e-06fe-4563-95c3-efa76975415b

But basically what you have to do is select the endpoint that you wish to extend and use the "Extend Endpoint" button. You will then have to give it a name and a version.

Then you can proceed to add the Quick Check entity. Here are some article that could help you with this. The article are titled "To Create a Custom Endpoint" but they contain sections about "To Add a Top-Level Entity to the Contract of the Endpoint", "To Add a Linked or Detail Entity to Another Entity" and "To Add Fields to an Entity" which are the information that you need.

Here are the article to Create the new entityt :

2018R2 : https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=709351cc-566a-47b3-b153-3a9fdd690ce0

2019R1 : https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=709351cc-566a-47b3-b153-3a9fdd690ce0

Comment: @samol1518 Thanks! I have newly extended endpoint now however whenever I make a request using that endpoint, I would get a "Endpoint [ExtendedDefault/17.200.002] not found". Any idea how this happened? Is there some processing time happening?

Comment: This seems like a different issue, you might want to create another question with all the required information so that someone might be able to help you with this. Information like screen shot of the endpoint and the request that you are making.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same case in url as you set it when create extended endpoint? This part is occasionally case sensitive.